# ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 
I am having a problem with a not responding script upon my page loading.  It happened while trying the Ajax toolkit file upload

This is from AddBlogPostAdvancedXSL.aspx

```
    <form id="form3" action="/" method="post" runat="server">   
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager 
          runat="server" 
          EnablePartialRendering="true" 
          ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" />
      <div class="filewant">
        <label for="WantFile">File</label>
        <asp:AsyncFileUpload 
          ID="AsyncFileUpload1" 
          runat="server" 
          onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" /> 
      </div>
    </form>
```

On the cs page or that i have

```
public partial class AddBlogPostAdvancedXSL : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Upon pageloading I get

> A script on this page may be busy, or
>   it may have stopped responding. You
>   can stop the script now, or you can
>   continue to see if the script will
>   complete.
>
> Script:
>   http://localhost:61527/AddBlogPostAdvancedXSL.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=RightColumn_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.50508.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3a0c8c847b-b611-49a7-8e75-2196aa6e72fa%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3ae4bd8421:12

If I hit continue script nothing happens I have to hit stop

If I try to use the upload box on the page I get a dialog and upon selecting a file the box turns red [with the selected filename inside the input] and I get an alert stating:

> Unhandled Exception: b.body is
>   undefined

Any ideas??
In case it is relevant, the page being initially requested is AddBlogPostAdvanced.aspx but the control itself resides on AddBlogPostAdvancedXSL..aspx the reason being is the AddBlogPostAdvanced simply contains XML data which includes AddBlogPostAdvancedXSL as an XSL sheet which contains all the layout and such for the page.  I do have the Asynch upload complete section on the proper cs for the page that loads the control..

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I tried to look at the script file that is supposed to be causing the error and when i try to load it in the browser I get

> Assembly "AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.50508.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" does not contain a script with hash code "12".

If I try to load the file without the :12 at the end it loads..

Comment: Since the script error references AdvancedBlogPostXSL.aspx, you should probably show us the contents of that file.

Comment: sorry I clarified, the markup and code given above was from that very page, I was just pointing out that the browser was in fact requesting AdvancedBlogPost.aspx which is just an XML file and THAT page is loading the above page which is the page containing the error reference

Comment: I think that the problem is exactly that the control is not existing on the page being requested.... that's why the hash error comes up the control is probably listed in a hash of controls for AdvancedBlogPost.aspx and it is really on AdvancedBlogPostXSL.aspx
As an experiment I made a separate page where the file upload works on it's own, stuck it in an iframe on my AdvancedBlogPostXSL.aspx and it works perfectly. I really dislike this solution though.... I guess the ajax controls aren't as versatile as I had hoped.